# query blob as varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a blob field returned to php as a varchar.

The field is a blob named "ssn".

If I do:

```
select cast(ssn as char) from staff
```

I get a bunch of entries (with what appears to be garbage that messes with my javascript).

I don't even know the column name to reference them.

If I try to grab it in PHP using thusly:

```
mysql_result( $result, $index, "ssn" )
```

I get:

> ... ssn not found in MySQL result ...

Any suggestions?

How do I avoid getting garbage back? Is it just that my client's ssn's are scrambled so I can't see them? Are there similar types I should consider casting to? And how do I reference it in my mysql_result() call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give columns aliases like this:

```
SELECT cast(ssn AS char) AS ssn_c FROM staff
```

Then you can use `ssn_c` to refer to the column.

Comment: It turned out my client had a decrypt function I didn't know about. Sometimes it feels like a large part of software development is reading people's minds.

Comment: The column alias syntax is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean with varchar return as string? If yes then you can just get the contents of the blob field as you normally would do with a varchar field - either use mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_object.